# Is there a way to only perform a block action at a given time interval in simulink?

Tags: simulation, matlab

I want to use my moving average block but ONLY for 30 seconds from the time from 10 sec to 40 sec in my 50 sec simulink simulation.

How can I do this? I don't want it to act from 0-10 seconds and from 40-50 seconds.

---

[image]

This is a picture of the system

Comment: I guess a selector between Direct/bypass  or Mov.Avg. Could work, but obviously depends of the kind of system you are Modeling - I suggest you to present the block diagram and further model details.

Comment: Peter Lyngbye - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it wasn't the answer to your original question. It was additional information, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. || Unless you are writing the *full and final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself and don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead, please edit the question to add new information & clarifications. Please see the [tour] and [help] for more rules. Thanks.

Comment: You could use the input with a switch, or a multiplier, controlled by a pulse. But that will not take care of the N+M-1 length of the convolution so, if you only wish to have that length, either set your filter to output the same length vector (if possible) or add the same control at the output. Or build your own filter that has each internal multiplier controlled by that pulse. I don't have Matlab so I can only provide some ideas.